# Silverlight Datagrid always calls ICollectionView.MoveCurrentTo with null

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, virtualization, icollectionview

I use https://github.com/jogibear9988/VirtualCollection a fork from me from the Project https://github.com/samueldjack/VirtualCollection

Now I have the problem, everytime I click on a Item in the Datagrid, the selected Item is set correctly to my object! But it also calls MoveCurrentTo of my VirtualCollection, and the parameter of this call is always null and not the current object!

Has anyone a clue what could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. The Problem was that IList.IndexOf was not correctly implemented!